# 00 часов или 24 часа?

Tags: употребление-слов

В каких случаях уместнее сказать "00 часов", а в каких — "24 часа"?

Comment: Насколько я знаю, такое (отличное) обозначение используется в официальных документах. Например, моя автомобильная страховка автоматически продлевается с "00.00 часов 27 марта до 24.00 часов 11 апреля". На слух сразо понятно, что контракт действует с полуночи с 26 на 27 марта до полуночи с 11 на 12 апреля, исключается всякая двусмысленность.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Сутки длятся двадцать четыре часа, а отсчёт времени в них начинается с ноля часов.

Единственное, когда служил в армии, ровно в полночь время называли "двадцать четыре - ноль-ноль", чтобы не запутать слушающего фразой "ноль-ноль - ноль-ноль". Дальше время называлось через "два нуля" или "ноль-ноль".

Answer (score 4):

Календарные сутки **кончаются** в 24:00, но **начинаются** в 00:00. 
24:00 21 ноября = 00:00 22 ноября.

Но уместность употребления может и должна определяться не подобными рассуждениями, а тем, насколько точно воспринимается и исключает двусмысленность. Поскольку некоторая двусмысленность все равно остаётся в обоих случаях, то лучше не заморачиваться и сказать "00:00 в ночь с 21-го на 22-ое". Такой "формат" времени был принят вообще для всех ночных рейсов "Аэрофлота" при общении с пассажирами. 
С тех пор много воды утекло...
А в армии - да, приянто 24:00, а не "ноль часов - ноль минут", это понятно и логично опять-таки с точки зрения восприятия на слух.

Answer (score 3):

Обратимся с ГОСТУ ([ГОСТ ИСО 8601 – 2001. Представление дат и времени](http://www.ifap.ru/library/gost/86012001.pdf)). Пункт 6.3 Представление полночи:

*Выбор одного из двух способов представления полночи (00:00 и 24:00 – М_Г) зависит от связи с датой или временным периодом. Представления, где hh имеет  значение 24, могут быть использованы только для представления конца периода времени.*

Как говорится, комментарии излишни.

Answer (score 0):

24 и 0 — одно время, но поскольку этот момент находится на границе дат х и х + 1, дали два названия: 24 и 0. 24 — последний момент даты х, а 0 — первый момент даты х + 1.

Comment: 1. очевидно, что если какой-то момент времени существует, то он имеет какой-то номер в зависимости от его места во временном промежутке. 2. очевидно что при окончании 24 часового цикла наступает время 0 часов (определение хронологической последовательности 0 и 24 часов, (24 потом 0( на границе 2 дат ))) 3. если это разное время между ними должен быть какой-то временной промежуток, иначе, это будет 1 момент времени. 4. Рассмотрим на примере даты х, если это предположение верно,

Comment: то после окончания даты х (24 часа) и перед началом дня х+1 есть какой-то временной промежуток, тогда выберем любой момент и этого промежутка, очевидно мы не сможем определить, к какой дате он относится, это означает, что у него нет номера во временном промежутке, что говорит о том что его не существует! Противоречие!

Comment: (почему это 1 момент)

Answer (score 0):

24 часа не существует. В соответствии с ГОСТом возможно употребление 24 часа исключительно с 00 минут и исключительно при указании периода (приставка до или дефис), так как "до" это то что не наступит.
То есть "с 15:00 до 24:00" - допустимо, "15:00 - 24:00" - допустимо, а "24:00" - недопустимо! В том числе и в армии (если в журнал занести несуществующее время, которое не показывается ни на каких часах, то запись неверная!)
Также известно достаточно много случаев, когда в справках указывали время наступления события "24:00" и справку признавали недействительной, так как такого времени не существует. А "01.01.2000 23:59" + 1 минута = "02.01.2000 00:00" (вообще другие сутки)